# How to reload angular ng-grid onclick?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using angular ng-grid like in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/50vJrs?p=preview

But I need to load with a new URL the grid when I click for example on the button "reload".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your getPagedDataAsync function to take a url parameter.  Then you can specify which url to load data from.

```
$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (url, pageSize, page, searchText) {
```

Inside the function you can get the data from the url parameter instead of the hardcoded value.

```
$http.get(url)
```

Now you can create a reload() function that calls getPagedDataAsync with a new url, and wire it up to a button.

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xdAejq?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Define the url in scope variable:

```
$scope.source="largeLoad.json";
```

Use this URL in your getPagedDataAsync function instead of an hardcoded source.

```
$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            $http.get($scope.source).success(function (largeLoad) {     
                data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
                $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
            });            
        } else {
            $http.get($scope.source).success(function (largeLoad) {
                $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

Finaly on reload change the source and call getPagedDataAsync again.

```
    $scope.reload=function(){
       $scope.source="largeLoad2.Json";
       $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, 1);
    };
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gObWbM?p=preview)

Comment: Jerrad was faster. His answer is basically the same as mine.